# Correct way to setup VPN/VLAN for small business NETGEAR FVS336G

Tags: vpn, ip, vlan, netgear

My current employer has a horrendous setup for his internet, 2 Virgin Media cabled lines with routers that you'd use at home.

So we've had Fibre Optic installed and a Pool of 5 Public IP Addresses.
We have our gateway and All information from our ISP.
We've also got a Netgear FVS336G. It's hard to describe what I want to do so i've included a picture, but I want to MAP some of our Public IP's to a Lan Port on the Router, so that I can plug in different devices and they have a different public IP, but I don't want to fix the IP's on each machine, i want to do it on the Router. Is this Possible?

I know its not the correct place to ask this but I thought I'd give it a shot.
Below is basically what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: 1) [NAT, AKA Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). 2) If they're springing for a fiber optic internet connection, you'd think they'd be willing to buy a real, managed router too. 3) Hire a consultant to get this designed properly and setup right.  Cheaping out on the setup of the foundation of your entire IT infrastructure is just idiotic, regardless of how common it is.

Comment: Can you assign an ip address to a switch or router port such that whatever device is plugged into that port inherits that ip address? No you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know the device, but a quick search reveals that it supports 1-1 NAT. So if you can configure multiple IP addresses on its public interface, it should be able to NAT an entire external/public IP over to a designated internal IP.

In the end, your server would have e.g.
`10.0.0.203` and the router will map your `xx.xx.xx.203` to that ip. etc.